# How to host a Django website inexpensively?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, web, hosting

I've recently been working on a Bug Tracking Software and my client wants the website up and running as soon as possible. I'm using the built in SQLite for the database.

What I can't figure out is, how do I host it as cheap as possible and can I use SQLite as a database for production.

It's a really small website running on the admin part of Django and based on what the client told me, there will be very minimal number of users. I've read that if the database is going to be huge, I should go for MySQL or MongoDB or any of the other database systems, but as I mentioned earlier, there aren't got to be a lot of users.

Is AWS a good option? If it is, how much would it cost me to get it up and running.

Comment: sqlite is poor!  the speed when fetching data from db is a bit nasty. [pythonanywhere](https://pythonanywhere.com) offers some cheap options, AWS is good one as well.

Comment: @Lemayzeur How slow are we talking? Becuase if its like 2-3 seconds, thats alright. Because all the app is doing is create, update and delete of like 7-10 tables and upload of like 1-3 images each time.

Comment: For such small actions and data, `SQLite` can do it. But I have always considered `SQLite` as a database for development, **it's my choice**.

Comment: Questions about product recommendations, services and databases, are off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Lemayzeur How do i migrate to mongoDB if i have to? Do you have a link to a tutorial? Im also looking for a tutorial on how to use bootstrap for the admin page.. And which one would be cheaper, pythonanywhere or AWS?

Comment: [Move to mongoDB](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/integrating-django-with-mongodb/)...  [django-admin-boostrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped)... | [Pythonanywhere is cheaper](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/pricing/) by far, but based on quality and performance, I would suggest [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html). **Let's stop this conversation, stuffs like that are off-topic as @KlausD. said**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted advice, that SQLite is slow, is wrong. From [the website](https://sqlite.org/whentouse.html):

> SQLite works great as the database engine for most low to medium traffic websites (which is to say, most websites). The amount of web traffic that SQLite can handle depends on how heavily the website uses its database. Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure is a conservative estimate, not a hard upper bound. SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic.

Make sure the file is on a good SSD drive, and you will be fine from a speed perspective.

However, concurrency may be an issue. Consider this advice (from the same page):

> If there are many client programs sending SQL to the same database over a network, then use a client/server database engine instead of SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not be great. Also, file locking logic is buggy in many network filesystem implementations (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not work correctly, two or more clients might try to modify the same part of the same database at the same time, resulting in corruption. Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it.

If you do use SQLite, then make sure you have a daily (or hourly) backup system in place, so your client can roll back to an earlier version if required. With the above advice in mind, it may be a good idea to store the file locally rather than accessing it over a network.

Remember that all database systems can suffer corruption, and all of them need a backup strategy.